# Read content of a set of file and check existence of a file in Ant

Tags: regex, file, ant

I'm new to Ant and I can't quite figure out how to do the following (if possible at all):
I have this basic code:

```
<copy todir="${mydir}">
    <fileset dir="${mydir2}" includes="**/*.html" />
        <filterchain>
            <replaceregex pattern="bla" replace="pla"/> <!-- regex1 -->
            <replaceregex pattern="doh" replace="dah"/> <!-- regex2 -->
        <filterchain>
</copy>
```

In the folder recursed by the fileset task, I have a bunch of html files, some contain a link to an existing file, some contain a link to an non-existing file.

Now what I'm trying to do is to:

1. Read each file of the fileset to extract a specific link that they all contain.
2. See if this link points to an existing file.
3. If it does, I apply regex1.
4. If it doesn't, I apply regex2 to remove the dead link.

So there's a bit of everything: conditions, retrieval of data from files to Ant to use it in other tasks, and it seems impossible to do!

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use [filterchain](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) with [tokenfilter replaceregex](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replaceregex), f.e. :

```
<copy todir="${mydir}">
 <fileset dir="${mydir2}" includes="**/*.html"/>
  <filterchain>
   <tokenfilter>
    <!-- regex 1 -->
    <replaceregex pattern="hello" replace="world" flags="gi"/>
    <!-- regex 2 -->
    <replaceregex pattern="doh" replace="dah"/>
   </tokenfilter>
  </filterchain>
</copy>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I believe this runs the 2 regexp on each file of the set, which is already what my code does. How can I read the current file and test the content to see which regex apply?

Comment: @Flag not so clear what you're asking for : check for existence of regex or replace  or ... ?!

Comment: I want to read the current file of the fileset "loop", apply a unique regexp to extract a link from the file, check if that link resolves to an existing file somewhere, and then apply a regexpression on the file I am reading.
I'll edit my main post to try and make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

It seems Ant-[contrib has a task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) that allows you to retrieve the result of a regexp andstore that in an ant property, that will do the job for sure to test the existence of the file and then go on a provided switch statement.